# What's giving me +1 to all skills?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Somehow, something I did/have has given me +1 to all skills:

[image]

I've searched through my entire inventory and checked my active effects and nothing says anything about buffing any skills, let alone *all* skills. And though I'm not complaining, I'm super curious. What could I have possibly done to give myself +1 to all my skills? And just to reiterate, **I have nothing equipped that buffs my skills**.

Comment: This concept makes it rather alluring to tri-spec. Very interesting.

Comment: @Emerica. You only need the first tier for this, which is 4 in all trees. So you can still get the benefit for skills despite using mostly only one tree by just switching your destiny before blacksmithing or dispelling or what have you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a Might/Finesse/Sorcery destiny by chance?

Going the tri-spec route gives you +1 to all skills as a destiny bonus (and it gets up to +3 at the higher levels).

Comment: I am going tri-spec now. I respeced recently in order to do this. That explains it :)